# get files and directories from a distant machine by sftp

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, treenode

I'm trying to connect my local machine to a distant machine and get a list of directories and files from by backend project
I'm using spring and angular 5

the problem is i didn't know what i have to do , i searched a lot and watched many tutorials but none of them had what i was looking for :(

i access to my distant machine using SFTP (with WinSCP) and i have to get those directories from one root path

how can i connect to the distant machine ?
and how can i retreive those directories ?
or Is there a tutorial for what i'm looking for ?
Is TreeNode the best way to do this ?

```
    List<TreeNode> directories = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
```

Comment: check Jsch library. You can use apache camel also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of files from an SFTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878209/how-to-get-list-of-files-from-an-sftp-server)

Comment: okay i will check it :)

Comment: If it did help, please accept that your question is duplicate.